# How to create custom panel layout with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class BattleShipsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // JButton arrays to hold buttons
        JButton[] userButtons = new JButton[100];
        JButton[] compButtons = new JButton[100];

        // Text for ships label
        String shipsText = "Ships      Size (Squares)" + "Carrier          5"
                + "Battleship       4" + "Destroyer        3"
                + "Patrol Boat      2";

        // Draw main window and set layout
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Battle Ships");
        window.setSize(1200, 1900);
        window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Draw top game panel
        JPanel gridPanTop = new JPanel();
        gridPanTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gridPanTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 400));
        gridPanTop.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        // Top panel text
        JLabel ships = new JLabel();
        ships.setText(shipsText);

        // Bottom panel buttons
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        Dimension submitSize = new Dimension(20, 20);
        submit.setSize(submitSize);

        // Draw bottom game panel
        JPanel panBottom = new JPanel();
        panBottom.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panBottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panBottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panBottom.add(submit);

        // Set position of game panels
        window.getContentPane().add(gridPanTop, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        window.getContentPane().add(panBottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Set border for grid buttons
        Border border = new LineBorder(Color.gray);

        // Draw panel for grids
        JPanel user = new JPanel();
        JPanel comp = new JPanel();
        user.setBackground(Color.gray);
        comp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        user.setBorder(border);
        comp.setBorder(border);

        // Set layout for grid panels
        user.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

        int x = userButtons.length;

        // Set user buttons as JButtons, set size and add to grid
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            userButtons[i] = new JButton();
            userButtons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
            user.add(userButtons[i]);
        }

        // Set computer buttons as JButtons, set size and add to grid
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            compButtons[i] = new JButton();
            compButtons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
            comp.add(compButtons[i]);
        }

        // Add panels to main frame and set visible
        window.pack();
        window.add(gridPanTop);
        window.add(panBottom);
        gridPanTop.add(user, BorderLayout.WEST);
        gridPanTop.add(comp, BorderLayout.EAST);
        gridPanTop.setVisible(true);
        panBottom.setVisible(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
        user.setVisible(true);
        comp.setVisible(true);

        // Start main game
        MainGame start = new MainGame();

    }
}
```

I have an assignment and am having lot of trouble creating the below panel layout in Java Swing. I have had no luck using any of the layouts.

[image]

Could anyone help my with this layout?

At present the code displays the following output:

[image: output of the above]

You can probably tell I am a beginner so please excuse rookie errors. The panel layout I have at the moment LOOKS like the ideal one I attached but clearly is not the correct layout as I'd like.

Comment: Looks like [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) with an empty `PAGE_START`.Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: I largely agree with @trashgod, border layout seems like it might be the best solution, but it depends on how extra space is to be assigned if the GUI is made larger by the user.

Comment: Thanks all, I will post what I try soon to show updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this with different layouts and compound of layouts (using subpanels). I would have used [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), that is definitely one of the most versatile layouts.

**Example code**

```
public class TestLayout extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7619921429181915663L;

    public TestLayout(){
        super("TestLayout");
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //Setup some test panel with labels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JLabel label1 =  new JLabel("Panel 1");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel1.add(label1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JLabel label2 =  new JLabel("Panel 2");
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel2.add(label2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JLabel label3 =  new JLabel("Panel 3");
        label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel3.add(label3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JLabel label4 =  new JLabel("Panel 4");
        label4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel4.add(label4,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Here goes the interesting code
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1,  new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.6, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2,
                2, 2), 0, 0));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel2,  new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.6, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2,
                2, 2), 0, 0));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel3,  new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.6, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2,
                2, 2), 0, 0));
        //next row
        this.getContentPane().add(panel4,  new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 3, 1, 1.0, 0.4, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2,
                2, 2), 0, 0));

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestLayout frame = new TestLayout();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Generated output**

[image: Output]

The key part of the GridBagLayout is the [GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)

```
new GridBagConstraints(columnNumber, rowNumber, columnSpan, rowSpan, columnWeigth, rowWeigth, alignment, fillType, insets, padX, pady)
```

see in example how `rowWeigth` is set to `0.6` for first row and `0.4` to second row so that first row takes up some more space (60%). Adjust them as you like (if you like same space, just set `0.5` to both).